# UV unwrapping question

Tags: uv

I've created a character mesh, but I still have certain parts to tweak like the face for an example and still have to decide how I want it to look. Is it safe to edit a mesh/model after uv unwrapping it?

Comment: I'd say no, not safe. Operations like Knife cut or Loopcut and another few allow to preserve UV after editing, but most modeling tools will modify your UV in a bad way.

Comment: Hey, thanks for clearly answering my question.